# write to serial port with javafx

Tags: java, serial-port

i am using jserialComm to communicate between java and arduino.
I want to write a string to Arduino.
this is my way for doing this:

```
rx = SerialPort.getCommPorts()[q];
     System.out.println(rx.getDescriptivePortName());
   rx.setBaudRate(CONFBAUDRATE);
   rx.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING, 0, 0);
   if(rx.openPort()){
OutputStream out = rx.getOutputStream();
         PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(out);    
}
```

Then:
i define this function:

```
private void writeTX(String command) {

writer.println(command);

}
```

When i call this function with a string. nothing happens.

I am receiving data periodically from arduino as well. i think there is a problem in this line of code:

> ```
>    rx.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING, 0, 0);
> ```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JavaFX. It is pure Java.

Comment: Yes u r right.
Sorry.